# Connect to SUSE using libssh

Tags: c++, linux, authentication, suse, libssh

I am trying to establish a connection using libssh(https://www.libssh.org/) to a machine with SUSE Enterprise operating system installed.

```
    ssh_options_set(tempSshSession, SSH_OPTIONS_HOST, host2Connect);
    ssh_options_set(tempSshSession, SSH_OPTIONS_LOG_VERBOSITY, &verbosity);
    ssh_options_set(tempSshSession, SSH_OPTIONS_PORT, &port);

    int rc = ssh_connect(tempSshSession);
    if(rc != SSH_OK) {
        printf("Error connecting to the localhost\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    // Authorized by the password.
    rc = ssh_userauth_password(tempSshSession, username, password);
```

After ssh_userauth_password() call it returns the response : "**SSH_AUTH_DENIED: Authentication failed: use another method**"

It works fine for operating systems like: Ubuntu, Linux Generic and CentOS.

Thanks

Comment: It's very tempting to downvote this question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. I only down vote malicious intent and gross negligance. I give you the benefit of the doubt. But hold tight others will not be as kind.

Comment: Is the username `root`?

Comment: With it working on other systems it would seem like it's an sshd configuration error (or difference at least). Can you check the configuration ? Can you establish a connection without the program ?

Comment: yes , it is....

Comment: @xyious from PuTTY it works

Comment: Just to be sure the easiest solution is covered.... are you sure the password is correct ?

Comment: @xyious yes. triple checked :)

Answer (score 0):

Check `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. You should find `PermitRootLogin forced-command-only` somewhere there. Set that to `yes` and your problem should be gone. Please keep in mind that there is a reason, why folks have decided to not allow per default root user/pass logins.

Comment: on all the other servers that I've tested it , I also used root as the user

Comment: these configuration settings deviate from distribution to distribution and administrator to administrator